# mailchimp lists/interest-groupings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

Anyone got an example on how to use mailchimp 2.0 interest-groupings 
I'm using the Gibbon gem in rails.

I tried below code.

```
Gibbon::API.lists.listInterestGroupings({:id => listId})
```

I get the following error. 
Gibbon::MailChimpError: MailChimp API Error: Unknown method "lists/listinterestgroupings" (code -32601)

I',m able to subscribe to my list using mailchimp subscribe method but when I try to pass it merge vars for groupings then it just saves it to the list but not my group

```
@merge_vars = ['GROUPINGS' => ['id' => listId, 'groups' => @myGroupName ]];
Gibbon::API.lists.subscribe({:id => listId, :email => {email:address}, :email_type => "html", :merge_vars => @merge_vars, :double_optin => false, :update_existing => true, :send_welcome => true})
```

Anyone ever get this to work. Please help this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

That's the way to use that method:

```
Gibbon::API.lists.interest_groupings(:id => listID)
```

from there you can get all the groups of the list, and get the group id that needs to be used in mergevars

```
@merge_vars = { :GROUPINGS => [{ :id => group_id, :name => "Group name", :groups => ['subgroup name']}] }
```

then just call your subscribe method

```
Gibbon::API.lists.subscribe({:id => listId, :email => {email:address}, :email_type => "html", :merge_vars => @merge_vars, :double_optin => false, :update_existing => true, :send_welcome => true})
```